# Navicat MySQL MacOS Code Complete on keypress?

Tags: autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts, navicat

I find Auto-complete very good on Navicat, but how I can show autocomplete on keypress? (I mean shortcut for it?) I see it just need to wait.. but I want to press some keys and activate it.. Can I? And How?

Answer (score 1):

I just read the documentation and found the following :

Code-Completion (**Available only in Full Version**)

> To activate the code-completion, just simply press '**.**' for the
>   available properties of database object currently in the scope.
>
> **Hint:** You may invoke code-completion by typing two characters or
>   pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> on your keyboard for SQL keywords.

Comment: I think he wants to be able to press enter after code complete happens. For me, enter just goes to a new line.

Comment: @ortonomy did you find the solution for the autocomplete on enter without selecting the top result first? It was working on older Navicat versions.

Comment: @user805528, yes -- I did!